# npm install -g ionic cordova error Unexpected end of JSON

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am running:

Windows 7
node v10.15.0
npm v6.4.1

trying to run npm install -g ionic cordova. Getting this error:

error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.2.0":{"name":"@ioni'

- I have run npm cache clean --force
- I have checked the registry, it is https://registry.npmjs.org/
- I have tried deleting the package-lock.json file at the root.
- I have tried unistalling and reinstalling node.js

Anybody have this issue?

Comment: In your project ? or Root Level ?

Comment: trying to install at root level

Comment: Check this:https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input/95215

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I have installed the latest version of node(v10.15.0) and npm (v6.4.1) and cant install ionic cordova when trying to run npm install -g ionic cordova so its not the same error as the forum post which was running ionic serve

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me...

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: If I try this I get this log error:  error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"inquirer","version'

Answer (score 0):

For those who experience this issue I found what the problem was in my specific case, maybe this will help you. I was connecting to the internet via the WIFI hotspot on my phone and as soon as I connected via a WIFI connection to a router connected to a fixed line the install worked no problems. I have no idea why, its no a speed issue, the connection speed on my phone is just as fast as the fixed line but anyway, I have got it working now.